# Styling a single Twitter feed with avatar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I'm having a slight issue styling a Twitter feed that I'm pulling through to my page.

I can't seem to get the image to sit on the left with a right margin of 15px and then the text will float right of the image. Currently it's overlapping on the image, but I can actually target the text to separate it, as the code is being generated by JS. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div id="twitter">
  <h2 class="twitter-header">Twitter</h2>
  <div id="tweet" ></div>
  <img class="followme" src="images/follow-me.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#gezzamondo .sidebar #twitter #tweet{
  color:#099!important;
}

#gezzamondo .sidebar #twitter .twitter-header{
  background-image:url(../images/twitter.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding-left:20px;
}

#gezzamondo .sidebar #twitter #tweet ul li img{
  float:left;
  margin-top:-25px;
}

#gezzamondo .sidebar #twitter #tweet ul li {
}

.followme{
  margin-top:15px;
  float:right;
}
```

**JS**

```
<!-- Twitter feed -->
<script src="http://twitterjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/twitter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  getTwitters('tweet', {
    id: 'gezzamondo',
    count: 1,
    enableLinks: true,
    ignoreReplies: true,
    clearContents: true,
    <!--template: '"%text%" <a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id%/">%time%</a>' -->
    template: '"%text%" <img src="%user_profile_image_url%" height="" width="" /><a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id%/">%time%</a>'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your CSS; you should be floating the image you want on the left "left".

```
.followme{
  margin-top:15px;
  float:left;
}
```

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/eMuVT/1/)